# Ruby - Iterating over String that iterates over array

Tags: ruby

I want to count vowels in Ruby. The code I have come up with, and it works for *one* word is:

```
def count_vowels(string)
  vowel = 0
  i = 0

  while i < string.length
    if (string[i]=="a" || string[i]=="e" || string[i]=="i" || string[i]=="o"|| string[i]=="u")
      vowel +=1
    end
  i +=1
  end
  return vowel
end
```

My question is this: If I have a *list* of words, rather than a single one, how do I iterate over the list of words to count the vowels in each word? Would it be something like this?

```
for each string_in list count_vowels
```

Comment: Do you want the total count of vowels or an array of the counts?

Comment: I want a count of vowels of each word in the array

Comment: Alright. Then the top answer should do it for you, unless you really want to use your function.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to count vowels it's as easy as using the `count` method:

`string.downcase.count('aeiou')`

If you have an array of strings, you can use `each` to iterate over them. You can also use `map`, which iterates over the collection and maps each result to an array.

```
['abc', 'def'].map do |string|
  { string => string.downcase.count('aeiou') }
end
```

This will return an array of hashes, with the keys being the strings and the values being the number of vowels.

Comment: I think you have an extra bracket or a missing one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-count):

```
string.downcase.count('aeiou')
```

If you have a list of words, you can do the following:

```
def count_vowels(string)
   string.downcase.count('aeiou')
end

list_of_words.map { |word|
   { word =>  count_vowels(word) }
}
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/322522)

Comment: This gives a total count of the vowels of all the words, not each separate word

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple. If you have the list of words as an array, you can just do this:

```
vowel_count = 0;
words.each { |word| vowel_count += count_vowels word }
```

Now, `vowel_count` has the amount of vowels in *every* word.

You could also do something like this, if you want an array of each count of vowels:

```
vowel_counts = words.map { |word| count_vowels word }
```